# WooCommerce get item wise shipping cost in cart page

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, cart

I am looking for a method in WooCommerce to fetch/get individual shipping price in cart.

```
foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $hash => $item) {
    # get $item wise shipping price.
}
```

I checked `/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php` class and I only found `get_cart_shipping_total()` which return the whole shipping price not the individual shipping price of each product.

TL;DR

[image]

I will highly appreciate if someone can guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: U want to calculate shipping for different product separately  and then add it to one shipping ? like the default ? or u want to show shipping in each line item ?

Comment: @Alice: Actually I do not want to show the individual shipping price in Ui, I just want to get the individual shipping price and accomplish some kind or internal business logic.

Comment: So this logic depends on category of the product ? or quantity of product or a line item ?

Comment: It depends on the line item, Admin will set the shipping price rule in woocommerce shipping section. WooCommerce will calculate the price of each line item and will tell the price separately of each line item.